# Android-sqlite Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from Cursor Window

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to get a value from the table.

```
 cursor=db.rawQuery("select value from '" + tableName + "' where key= '" + name + "' ",null);

if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String value= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
                return value;
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
```

I get the exception:

```
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from Cursor Window.Make sure cursor is initialised correctly before accessing data from it.
```

When I use:

```
        cursor.getString(0);
```

I am able to get the value I need.

If I use,

```
       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
```

I get the exception.

HEre is the snapshot of my table:
[image]

Comment: Your variable tableName is null.

Comment: sry....i posted the wrong error...i updated the question @GabeSechan

Comment: table name is not null and the cursor is also not null.

Comment: It was with the original exception you gave us.

Comment: With this code-  its not finding a column named value.  So getColumnIndex returns -1, which is an invalid index.

Comment: i agree... but that was a mistake....i copy pasted the old exception I got...i resolved it by givng the table name properly!

Comment: as u can see in the snapshot, the table does have the column named 'value'....how to make cursor find it properly ?

Comment: Is it named value or VALUE? SQL is case sensitive for table and column names, even though it isn't for keywords.

Comment: As a total aside-  don't make your query using string append for values like that.  Appending variables to SQL text is asking for SQL injection bugs.  Use bind variables instead.

Comment: its named as VALUE

Comment: Then getColumnIndex("VALUE");

Comment: i agree with the sql injection thing....after i set the basic CRUD going on...i will take care of the sql injeciton attack!

Comment: ok...let me try that.,

Comment: u r right!!! making it caps worked!

Comment: Please provide an answer, and I will accept it @GabeSechan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table and column names in SQL are case sensitive.  Since your column is named "VALUE", you need to getColumnIndex("VALUE")

Comment: And BTW, if you're not going to check the return value, you might as well use the [getColumnIndexOrThrow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndexOrThrow%28java.lang.String%29) method -- it would give you more useful error messages if/when it fails.

Comment: For what it's worth, in SQL the names are *not* case sensitive but in `Cursor` API they are.

Comment: Its implementation specific.  Some dbs are case sensitive, some aren't.  SQLite is.  Its safer to assume it is when writing generic SQL code.

Answer (score -3):

The Table you created must have a column with name _id. it won't work until you add column with column index "_id".

if you do not have any column with column index "_id". Explicitly uninstall your app from settings->app manager. and re-run you app after adding required column.

Comment: SQLite automatically adds an id column.  Also that's not a requirement, you can create a table without one.